# Spreadsheet tracker

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im having trouble with an script that posts the outcome twice, I have reviewed the script but I cant find the issue.

The script gets the `"Timestamp"`, `"Cell address"`, `"Column label"` and `"Value entered"` and post it on the sheet named `"Tracker"` but it gets posted twice

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheetsToWatch = ['Responses'];
  // name of the sheet where the changelog is stored
  var changelogSheetName = "Tracker";

  var timestamp = new Date();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  // if it is the changelog sheet that is being edited, do not record the change
  if (sheetName == changelogSheetName) return;

  // if the sheet name does not appear in sheetsToWatch, do not record the change
  var matchFound = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {
    if (sheetName.match(sheetsToWatch[i])) matchFound = true;
  }
  if (!matchFound) return;

  var columnLabel = sheet.getRange(/* row 1 */ 1, cell.getColumn()).getValue();
  var rowLabel = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), /* column A */ 1).getValue();

  var changelogSheet = ss.getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);
  if (!changelogSheet) {
    // no changelog sheet found, create it as the last sheet in the spreadsheet
    changelogSheet = ss.insertSheet(changelogSheetName, ss.getNumSheets());
    // Utilities.sleep(2000); // give time for the new sheet to render before going back
    // ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
    changelogSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "Cell address", "Column label", "Value entered"]);
    changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  }
  changelogSheet.appendRow([timestamp, cell.getA1Notation(), columnLabel, cell.getValue()]);
}
```

Comment: My guess is you have - in addition to using a reserved function name - also given this script an installed trigger. Thus, the script itself is activated twice. Note that you cannot see the triggers created by other users in the UI, so it is possible some other user created the installed trigger.

Comment: I went to all people involved and there is a trigger, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's method documentation makes it seem like you can programmatically check for the existence of some other user's trigger with a function like this:

```
function triggerLogger() {
  // Read installed triggers for the project.
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var installedReport = {};
  triggers.forEach(function (t) { installedReport[t.getUniqueId()] = {
      event: t.getEventType(),
      calledFunction: t.getHandlerFunction(),
      source: t.getTriggerSource(),
      source_id: t.getTriggerSourceId() || "Time-based triggers have no source id."
  }});

  // Read "simple" triggers for the project by checking for globals that start with "on".
  var simpleReport = {};
  for (var thing in this)
    if (thing.indexOf("on") === 0 && thing.length > 2)
      simpleReport[String(thing)] = {def: this[thing]};

  var possibleSimple = Object.keys(simpleReport).length,
      message = "Trigger report: " + triggers.length + " installed";
  if (possibleSimple) message += ", " + possibleSimple + " possible simple triggers";
  message += ".";

  // Log to Stackdriver (so the report can be viewed sensibly).
  console.log({
    message: message,
    installed: Object.keys(installedReport).length ?
        installedReport : "No detected installed triggers.",
    simple: possibleSimple ?
        simpleReport : "No simple triggers used",
    reportRunAs: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
  });
}
```

But the [`getProjectTriggers()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getProjectTriggers()) method, despite claiming to get all of the current project's installed triggers, will only obtain **your** installed triggers for the document, even if you are the owner of the document.

Note that this behavior is [accepted as a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764532) (meaning someone, someday will fix it). If you would like to feel that you have done your part to accelerate that timeline, please **star** that issue:
[image: where to star]